# Tar list of files resulting from command

Tags: linux, bash, tar, command-substitution, process-substitution

I have a folder with 200k pdf files and want to tar them. Which of the following solutions would be better? I suspect the command substitution might run into problems with the huge number of files because of command line length limitations.

[Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

```
tar -cf out.tar -T <(compgen -G '*.pdf')
```

[Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) (Might break command length limitations?)

```
tar -cf out.tar `compgen -G '*.pdf'`
```

Comment: Why not using `xargs` and the append mode of `tar`? Something like `compgen -G '*.pdf' | xargs | tar --append -f out.tar`.

Comment: The first one if command line length is a potential issue, of course.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet That would be another option, but process substitution seems simpler to me

Comment: @Roland Sure. But `xargs` was especially designed to solve the command line length limitations. It has some other nice properties like the NUL input separator, for instance, that you could want to use in case some of your files have spaces in their name.

Answer (score 0):

I tested.

Process Substitution woks, Command Substitution breaks due to argument list length.

I also tested with `tar --append` with both `find` and `xargs`. The results suggest that append is much slower.

Comment: This would be inefficient, no?

Comment: Yes @Roland, I updated the answer.

Comment: Process substitution fails if you are using a shell that doesn't support it, and argument-list length is an OS-dependent constraint, with some operating systems allows arbitrarily large argument lists.